# Excel Unicode appearing literally in cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I've got strings in an Excel table that have literal unicode values, i.e. &#160; and I'm trying to compare them to another string which instead of the unicode string, has simply a space.

How do I do this? I tried this:

```
textref = replace(textref, ChrW$(160), " ")
```

as well as

```
textref = replace(textref, "&#160;", " ")
```

and I can't seem to get it to work. Alternatively, is there a way to make Excel render the text as spaces?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've been trying to do this with Regex and I still can't get the program to view the characters as literal

Comment: Can you provide some sample of your `textref` ? It will be easier to test the validity of a solution if we have your cell content.

Comment: Sure, for example: "As appears in ibid. (p.&#160;941.)"

Comment: I managed to get some result with the Excel function `SUBSTITUTE`. Can you also provide the expected result ?

Comment: Can you actually update your OP and include sample data and expected results. Possibly a screenshot even.

Comment: You know what, SUBSTITUTE actually does work on the sheet. But it doesn't work in VBA, either as the recommended REPLACE function or by calling substitute via WorksheetFunction.Substitute.

Comment: I just went into my home computer to make a screenshot of this and there is no issue on my home computer (the problem is at work). This leads me to believe that there is some setting in Excel that tells it to treat these characters as a string or as what they represent in Unicode, in this case a space.